# How to recursively compile a collection of packages in Java

Tags: java, compilation, package

Suppose one has a java project which consists of several packages, subpackages etc, all existing in a folder "source". Is there a direct way to copy the structure of the folders in "source" to a "classes" folder and then recursively compile all the .java files, placing the .class files in the correct locations in "classes"?

Comment: also : there is no "classes file", there will be A class file for EVERY .java-file - and one MAY aggregate then into one single JAR-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For larger projects a recommend using a build tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or the newer and faster [Gradle](http://gradle.org). Once you've configured one of them for your needs, it's very easy to do the job by calling `mvn build` or `gradle build`.

If these tools seem to heavy for your purpose, you may have a look at [Ant](http://ant.apache.org). A simple ant example:

```
<project default="compile">
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <javac srcdir="source" destdir="bin"/>
</target>
</project>
```

and then run `ant` from the command line. See [this thread for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively).

Comment: Thank you Tobias, your answer is exactly what I was looking for! In the past I had used GNU make as a building tool for other tasks. Do you think it makes sense to use make to manipulate java files, or is it too outdated compared to the building tools you recommended? Thanks once more!

Comment: Make is a very flexible build tool usable for building everything. Of course you could build your java project with `make` but than you would and up configuring everything on your own.

Build tools like Gradle, Maven and Ant are developed especially for Java projects though they could also be used for projects. 

In most cases, it's easier to use these tools because they provide a specific structure and some pre configured tasks and can be extended by plugins according to your needs. 
Most Java IDEs provide support for Maven and Gradle and especially the documentation of Gradle is awesome.

Comment: I see; make is more of an all-purpose tool. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

- There are no "bin files" in Java, this language only compiles
  bytecode
- [Compiling multiple packages using the command line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512603/compiling-multiple-packages-using-the-command-line-in-java)
- Eclipse : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7218929/351861
- via console : `javac folder1/*.java folder2/*.java folder3/*.java`